# Efficient algorithm to generate random multigraph (undirected) given nodes and degree

Tags: python, graph

I wrote a simple algorithm to generate 1000 random graphs given total nodes and associated node degree. Graph is undirected with multiple edges and no self-loops. My current algorithm is very slow:

Graph properties: no self-loops, undirected, multiple edges (i.e. many edges b/w same pair of vertices)

- Pick 2 random node ids from node list using np.random
- Check if node degree is full, if not connect 2 nodes and add to dictionary with connections
- If a certain node has reached node degree removed it from list so it is not picked again.
- randomness is graph generation is crucial as graphs form part of a statistical test
- Algorithm reaches exception, where only 1 node is left out (mostly the node with large degree compared to other nodes) In such a case I take the intermediate generated graph and start breaking random edges and connecting these edges to the left out node until all nodes reach their original node degree.
- This above is the bottleneck I suppose as I generate a graph and degenerate it later due to the exception.

```
from collections import defaultdict

for iteration in range(1000):  # 1000 random graphs
    all_stop = False
    all_stop_2 = False
    count = count +1
    
    success_dict = defaultdict(list)  
    popped_dict = defaultdict(dict)
    grid_dens_dict = defaultdict(set) # final graph being built
        
    
    # pfxlinks = [edge1,edge2,edge3,edge4,........edgen] # just a placeholder edge list to help me identify which node connected with which node in success_dict 
    pfxlinks = [i for i in range(842814)]     # total 842814 edges each connected to a node in grid_ids_withlinks , so if we add all node degrees in grid_ids_withlinks we get (842814 * 2)
    

    
    grid_ids_withlinks = {1107415: 751065,1125583: 15256,1144686: 108969,1115625: 17038,1081048: 6749,1103814: 6476,1108340: 107431,1111992: 45946,1117451: 3594,1093803: 10860,1117452: 2126,1089226: 52518,1082859: 21211,1105613: 94587,1092862: 43891,1083786: 17073,1092899: 999,1141954: 4347,1106506: 2072,1094690: 119736,1116547: 3284,1104705: 2404,1135637: 3815,1121070:16598,1087417: 4514,1103777: 310,1114682: 4265,1091948: 5468,1093788: 2176,              1098316: 2067,1105597: 19090,1141055: 8454,1097427: 3041,1092875: 4159,1086500: 2204,1095619: 9732,1087430: 2041,1112884: 2167,1097413: 17056,1107414: 34769,1111088: 2025,1083768: 2176,1130180: 1886,              1144699: 988,1146499: 6818,1111081: 12509,1104687: 6186,1092866: 4272,1091037: 3,1121044: 39,1098333: 294,1118359: 27,1151091: 21,1107441: 10766,1141094: 3523,1102898: 53,1115634: 2199,1100140: 4347,1086515: 3029,1116505: 238,1082883: 4070,1118366:2065,1102866: 1590,1115631: 4345,1091990: 2131,1144703: 4053,1075589: 19,1081062: 2124,1097425: 11,1133804: 8,1112864: 158,1088307: 112,1138312: 112,1127446: 6245,1108356: 155,1082874: 6315,1115640: 3978,1107432: 2234,1131077: 2032,1115590: 2672,1094696: 13,1136502: 52,1094683: 20,1110183: 2,1113821: 56,1106515: 6,1120183: 11,1083765: 23,1101079: 6,1091944: 12,1085599: 10,1083783: 25,1148339: 6}

# dict with node_id : node degree (total nodes: 93)

    
    for pfxpair in pfxlinks:
        start_put = False    
        end_put = False 
        
        if all_stop_2 == True:
            break
        
        while True:
            
            if all_stop == True:
                all_stop_2 = True
                break
           
            try:
                grid_start_id, grid_end_id = (np.random.choice(list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys()),size = 2, replace = False)) # get 2 random node ids
                grid_start_id = int(grid_start_id)
                grid_end_id = int(grid_end_id)
                
                if start_put == False:
                    
                    start_value = grid_dens_dict.get(grid_start_id)    # if node id exists in my dict and node degree hasnt reached capacity
                    
                    start_process_condition = (not start_value) or ( (start_value) and (len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) < grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id]) )
                    if start_process_condition:
                        grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id].add(pfxpair)
                        start_put = True
                    
                        if len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) == grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id]: # node degree for node full, remove from dict
                            
                            try:
                                #print('deleted key: ',grid_start_id, 'with size:',grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id],'Capacity:',grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id])
                                popped_dict[grid_start_id] = {'orig_capacity': grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id],'size':len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) }
        
                                grid_ids_withlinks.pop(grid_start_id)
                            
                            except:
                                print('already popped')
                else:
                    print('check')
                              
                if end_put == False: 
                    
                                        
                    end_value = grid_dens_dict.get(grid_end_id)
                    if (not end_value) or (end_value and (len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) < grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id])):
                        grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id].add(pfxpair)
                        end_put = True
                        
                        if len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) == grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id]:
                            try:
                                #print('deleted key: ',grid_end_id, 'with size:',grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id],'Capacity:',grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id])
                                popped_dict[grid_end_id] = {'orig_capacity': grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id],'size':len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) }
        
                                grid_ids_withlinks.pop(grid_end_id)
        
                            except: # only 1 node left with large degree, start breaking edges
                                print('already popped')
                else:
                    print('check')
                
                if (start_put == False and end_put == True):      # only end while when both nodes have been assigned a link
                    grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id].discard(pfxpair)
                    end_put = False
                if (start_put == True and end_put == False):
                    grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id].discard(pfxpair)
                    start_put = False
        
                        
                if start_put == True and end_put == True:
                    success_dict[pfxpair].append((grid_start_id,grid_end_id))
        
                    break

       
            except:
                    #print('In except block')
                    grid2grid = defaultdict(list)
                    for k,v in success_dict.items():
                        grid2grid[v[0][0]].append(v[0][1])
                        grid2grid[v[0][1]].append(v[0][0])
                    
                    # ppick 2 random gridids
                    while True:
                        pop_id1, pop_id2 = (np.random.choice(list(grid_dens_dict.keys()),size = 2, replace = False)) # get 2 random node ids for popping
                        pop_id1 = int(pop_id1)
                        pop_id2 = int(pop_id2)
                        if (pop_id1 != list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0] and pop_id2 != list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0] and  (pop_id1 in grid2grid[pop_id2] and pop_id2 in grid2grid[pop_id1])):  ##have an assigned link 
                            grid2grid[pop_id1].remove(pop_id2)
                            grid2grid[pop_id2].remove(pop_id1)
                            grid2grid[list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0]].append(pop_id1)
                            grid2grid[list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0]].append(pop_id2)
                            grid2grid[pop_id1].append(list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0])
                            grid2grid[pop_id2].append(list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0])
        
        
                            
                        if len(grid2grid[list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0]]) == grid_ids_withlinks[list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0]]:
                            for k,v in grid2grid.items():
                                grid2grid[k] = Counter(v)
                            
                            if len(all_itr_list) != 0:
                                # check if current grpah same as any previous
                                for graph in all_itr_list:
                                    #same_counter = 0
                                    #for a,b in graph.items():
                                        
                                    shared_items = {k: graph[k] for k in graph if k in grid2grid and graph[k] == grid2grid[k]}
                                    len(shared_items)
                                    
                                    if len(shared_items) == grid_ids_withlinks:                               # total no of grids
                                        #print('no of same nodes: ',len(shared_items))
                                        break
                    
                                
                                
                            all_itr_list.append(grid2grid)
                            
                            filename = 'path'
                            with open(filename,'wb') as handle:
                                pickle.dump(grid2grid, handle)
                            all_stop = True

                            break
        
        print('iteration no:',count)
        if all_stop == False:
            grid2grid = defaultdict(list)
            for k,v in success_dict.items():
                grid2grid[v[0][0]].append(v[0][1])
                grid2grid[v[0][1]].append(v[0][0])
            
            for k,v in grid2grid.items():
                grid2grid[k] = Counter(v)
            all_itr_list.append(grid2grid)

            filename = 'path'
            with open(filename,'wb') as handle:
                pickle.dump(grid2grid, handle)
```